# What's the warning under -fgcse about invoking -O2 on programs that use computed gotos?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-flags

I've written a program using computed `goto`s (yes, I know) and would like to know whether I can compile it with `-O2`. However, GCC's documentation is being rather unhelpful:

> Please note the warning under `-fgcse` about invoking `-O2` on programs that use computed gotos.

This message is profoundly unhelpful, and searches for similar terms just come up with [that same documentation page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

What is this warning? What does it mean for my code?

Comment: You have to find the documentation for the `-fgcse` on that page. It says "When compiling a program using computed gotos, a GCC extension, you may get better run-time performance if you disable the global common subexpression elimination pass by adding -fno-gcse to the command line"

Comment: @nos Oh. Well, it didn't show up when I looked it up online, so I think this question still has _merit_ (though doesn't deserve upvotes). Do you want to write the answer, or shall I?